# How to properly iterate through a list containing only strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on this picnic game that asks the number of players, their names, and appends the names to a list. It then asks for an item and if the first letter of the item matches the first letter of the name, it says 'You can come', and if it doesn't match, it says 'You can't go'. The setup() and main() functions work perfectly.

```
def setup():
    number_players = 0
    player_name = ''
    counter = 0
    player_name_list = []

    number_players = int(input('How many players? '))
    for players in range(number_players):
        counter += 1
        player_name = input('Player ' + str(counter) + ' Name: ')
        player_name_list.append(player_name)

    return player_name_list, player_name


def game(player_name, player_name_list):
    item_to_bring = ''

    for names in player_name_list:
        print(names)
        print('Hi, ' + str(player_name))
        item_to_bring = input('We\'re going on a picnic. What will you bring: ')

        if item_to_bring[0] == player_name[0]:
            print('You can come!')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you can\'t come.')


def main():
    player_name, player_name_list = setup()
    counter = 0
    while counter == 0:
        game(player_name, player_name_list)
        play_again = input('Would you like ot play again? (y or n) ')
        if play_again == 'y':
            counter = 0
        else:
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            counter += 1

main()
```

The problem is that the for loop in the game() function iterates through the characters of the final name instead of going name by name. I've changed as many things as I can think of, but I'm stuck. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You unpacking is wrong in first life of main() function. It should be:

```
player_name_list , player_name = setup()
```

It should follow the order your *setup()* function returns which is:

```
return player_name_list, player_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two main issues in your code. As mentioned in Gopal Gautam's answer, you're unpacking the values returned from `setup` in the wrong order. They should be returned like this:

```
player_name_list, player_name = setup()
```

Otherwise, the values of `player_name_list` will be what you expect `player_name` to be and vice versa.

With this change in place, the code will still not work properly. If you enter, say, 3 players, Bob, Fred, and Joe, in that order, it will greet you as Joe every time and compare the first letter of your input with "J".

This is because, in your `setup` function, you define `player_name` as a different value each iteration of the loop. If, as in the above example, you enter Bob, then Fred, then Joe, `"Joe"` will be stored in `player_name` after the last iteration of the loop. `"Joe"` is then returned as `player_name`, thus `player_name` in the `main` function will be `"Joe"`. `main` then passes it as a parameter to `game`.

In the `game` function, `item_to_bring[0]` is compared to `player_name[0]` each iteration of the loop, meaning, with the above example, the first letter of the input is being compared to `"J"` each time because `player_name` is `"Joe"`, rather than being compared to `"B"`, then "`f`", then `"J"`.

In other words, your `game` function is only using the last player name you entered, rather than a different one for each iteration as intended.

To fix this, simply change your `game` function to the following:

```
def game(player_name, player_name_list):
    item_to_bring = ''

    for names in player_name_list:
        print(names)
        print('Hi, ' + str(names))
        item_to_bring = input('We\'re going on a picnic. What will you bring: ')

        if item_to_bring[0] == names[0]:
            print('You can come!')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you can\'t come.')
```

Now, it will iterate through each name in `player_name_list` as intended, and it will compare the first letter of `item_to_bring` with the first letter of `names` each iteration.

With this change in place, you actually don't need the `player_name` parameter at all, as it is the same as the last element in `player_name_list`. You can safely remove it as a parameter in `game` and a return value in `setup`.

With all these changes in place, your code should look like this:

```
def setup():
    number_players = 0
    player_name = ''
    counter = 0
    player_name_list = []

    number_players = int(input('How many players? '))
    for players in range(number_players):
        counter += 1
        player_name = input('Player ' + str(counter) + ' Name: ')
        player_name_list.append(player_name)

    return player_name_list


def game(player_name_list):
    item_to_bring = ''

    for names in player_name_list:
        print(names)
        print('Hi, ' + str(names))
        item_to_bring = input('We\'re going on a picnic. What will you bring: ')

        if item_to_bring[0] == names[0]:
            print('You can come!')
        else:
            print('Sorry, you can\'t come.')


def main():
    player_name_list = setup()
    counter = 0
    while counter == 0:
        game(player_name_list)
        play_again = input('Would you like to play again? (y or n) ')
        if play_again == 'y':
            counter = 0
        else:
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            counter += 1

main()
```